# What does cumulative count cut actually do?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, digital-image-processing

I have a grayscale satellite image (16-bit image) which is dull (low brightness). When I apply cumulative count cut from 2 to 98 percent (Properties -> Min-Max Setting -> Cumulative count cut), it improves the visibility. I also tried to do histogram equalization but the result is not as good. So what does the cumulative count cut actually do to the image?

Comment: Have a look at the figure http://aaronaschroedergeog338.blogspot.com/2013_11_01_archive.html

Answer (score 5):

I think, it does the same than `numpy.nanpercentile`.
It takes the 2nd and the 98th percentile of your grey values and sets it as the colour-map minimum and maximum. Like colour stretch it doesn't alter your data but the way your data is displayed.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanpercentile.html

(I used `np.nanpercentile` to plot my data with matplotlib and it looks almost the same as it looks in QGIS. Probably you don't need my answer anymore, but in case others wonder as well or want know how to achieve a similar colour representation  using Python and matplotlib...)