# Cumulative Count Cut Stretch in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to visualize my raster in order to highlight certain trees.

In QGIS, it looks like this (default settings: stretched to min/max and cumulative count cut of 2.0 - 98.0):

[image]

And I want to look like this (visualized using ArcGIS Pro's Percent Clip Stretch, as described below).

[image]

In ArcGIS pro, under raster symbology, one can select the stretch type "Percent Clip", which "cuts off percentages of the highest and lowest values," as shown in the following screenshots. (Note: I'm a bit confused what min and max represent, compared to QGIS's cumulative count cut min and max).

[image]
[image]

How would I achieve the same behavior in QGIS? After fiddling with values, the following settings yield the closest image I was able to produce.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a description of Cumulative count cut at [What does cumulative count cut actually do?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324888/what-does-cumulative-count-cut-actually-do)

I set the Contrast enhancement to "Stretch and Clip to MinMax":

[image]

and the Cumulative count cut to 0.1%/99.9%:

[image]

and that was enough to get what looked like a reasonable result and approximation of the ArcGIS output. That said, I was unable to get close to your result using 0%/50% so I'm not sure if you had other settings tweaked? I am using QGIS 3.34.0.

[image]

You can see from the histogram that the raw image is very concentrated around the lower middle, and that without some contrast is going to be very flat.

[image]

If you want a consistent result eg if you have lots of rasters with a similar colour range, you may be better off setting User defined ranges for each colour band.